# image link in Yii framework

Tags: yii

hello friends I am newbie to YII. I have an image . After calling that image in Yii its code like is this

```
<img class="deals_product_image" src="<?php echo MPFunctions::uploaded_image_url($data->item_display_image()->file_ufilename); ?>" alt="<?php echo $data->name; ?>" />
```

in general html it is doing like this

```
<img alt="women jackets" src="files/items/images/4db3b3b6a7c06/womens-jacket-thumb.jpg" class="deals_product_image">
```

Now I want that this image should be a href link like

```
 <a href="files/items/images/4db3b3b6a7c06/womens-jacket-thumb.jpg img src="files/items/images/4db3b3b6a7c06/womens-jacket-thumb.jpg class="deals_product_image"/> </a>
```

so for this I used code  like this

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('', array('items/viewslug', 'slug'=>$data->slug)); ?>
```

But it is not showing any link tag like `<a href="">`
so can any one tell me what should I do?What should I write in between `''` tags?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should simply give the html for the `<img>` tag as the first parameter:

```
$imageUrl = MPFunctions::uploaded_image_url($data->item_display_image()->file_ufilename);
$image = '<img class="deals_product_image" src="'.$imageUrl.'" alt="'.$data->name.'" />';

echo CHtml::link($image, array('items/viewslug', 'slug'=>$data->slug));
```

By the way, you can use `CHtml::image` to create the `<img>` tag as well:

```
$imageUrl = MPFunctions::uploaded_image_url($data->item_display_image()->file_ufilename);
$image = CHtml::image($imageUrl, $data->name, array('class' => 'deals_product_image'));

echo CHtml::link($image, array('items/viewslug', 'slug'=>$data->slug));
```